# Changing the QPushButton region mask in its subclass to create a RoundButton

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, desktop

I am trying to create a round button by subclassing and setting the region mask so that I can reuse it in my project. I know we can override paintEvent method and draw a circle to show it as a round button. But the problem with this approach is that if user clicks outside the circle (but within button rect) it will be treated as a button click. This problem we don't see when set the region mask.

I tried to set the region by calling setmask method inside resizeEvent/paintEvent. In either of case, button will be blank. I am trying to figure out the place inside the subclass to set the region mask.

### RoundAnimatingButton.h ->

```
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
class CRoundAnimatingBtn;
}

class CRoundAnimatingBtn : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CRoundAnimatingBtn(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~CRoundAnimatingBtn();

    void StartAnimation(QColor r);
    void StopAnimation();

public slots:    
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e);


private:
    Ui::CRoundAnimatingBtn *ui;


    bool        m_Spinning;

    // QWidget interface
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e) override;
};

#endif // ROUNDANIMATINGBTN_H
```

### RoundAnimatingButton.cpp

```
CRoundAnimatingBtn::CRoundAnimatingBtn(QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton (parent)
    , ui(new Ui::CRoundAnimatingBtn)
    , m_Spinning(false)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}



CRoundAnimatingBtn::~CRoundAnimatingBtn()
{
    delete ui;
}

void CRoundAnimatingBtn::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPushButton::paintEvent(e);

    if(m_Spinning)
    {
    // Animating code
    }
}

void CRoundAnimatingBtn::StartAnimation(QColor r)
{
    m_Spinning=true;
    startTimer(5);

}

void CRoundAnimatingBtn::StopAnimation()
{
    m_Spinning=false;
    this->update();
}


void CRoundAnimatingBtn::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e)
{
    if(m_Spinning)
        this->update();
    else
        killTimer(e->timerId());
}

void CRoundAnimatingBtn::DrawRing()
{

 }


void CRoundAnimatingBtn::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{

      // -----------------------------------
      // This code didn't work
      // -----------------------------------
        QRect rect = this->geometry();
        QRegion region(rect, QRegion::Ellipse);
        qDebug() << "PaintEvent Reound button - " << region.boundingRect().size();
        this->setMask(region);

        // ----------------------------------

        // ------------------------------------
        // This code worked
        // -------------------------------------
        int side = qMin(width(), height());
        QRegion maskedRegion(width() / 2 - side / 2, height() / 2 - side / 2, side,
                             side, QRegion::Ellipse);
        setMask(maskedRegion);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far -- preferably a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt doc. provides a sample for “non-rectangular” widgets – [Shaped Clock Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html).

(Un-)Fortunately, I remembered this not before I got my own sample running.

I started in Qt doc. with

> ### [`void QWidget::setMask(const QBitmap &bitmap)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask)
>
> Causes only the pixels of the widget for which *bitmap* has a corresponding 1 bit to be visible. If the region includes pixels outside the [rect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#rect-prop) of the widget, window system controls in that area may or may not be visible, depending on the platform.
>
> Note that this effect can be slow if the region is particularly complex.
>
> The following code shows how an image with an alpha channel can be used to generate a mask for a widget:
>
> ```
> QLabel topLevelLabel;
> QPixmap pixmap(":/images/tux.png");
> topLevelLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
> topLevelLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask());
> ```
>
> The label shown by this code is masked using the image it contains, giving the appearance that an irregularly-shaped image is being drawn directly onto the screen.
>
> Masked widgets receive mouse events only on their visible portions.
>
> **See also** [mask()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mask), [clearMask()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#clearMask), [windowOpacity()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop), and [Shaped Clock Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html).

(When reading this, I still missed the link to example.)

At first, I prepared a suitable pixmap for my purpose – `dialog-error.png`:

[image: dialog-error.png]

for which I converted an SVG from one of my applications.

I tried to apply it to a `QPushButton` as icon and as mask. This looked very strange. I'm not quite sure what exactly was the problem:
- using the resp. `QPushButton` as toplevel widget (i.e. main window)
- the fact that `QPushButton`s icon rendering and the mask may not match concerning position or size.

Without digging deeper, I changed the code and fixed both issues in next try:

- making a derived button (like described by OP)
- using the button as non-toplevel widget.

This worked soon. I added some code to make the effect more obvious:

- a mouse press event handler for main window to show whether shape is considered correctly
- a signal handler to show whether clicks on button (in shape) are received correctly.

So, I came to the following sample – `testQPushButtonMask.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow: public QWidget {

  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent)
    { }
    virtual ~MainWindow() = default;
    MainWindow(const MainWindow&) = delete;
    MainWindow& operator=(const MainWindow&) = delete;

  protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override;

};

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  qDebug() << "MainWindow::mousePressEvent:" << pQEvent->pos();
  QWidget::mousePressEvent(pQEvent);
}

class RoundButton: public QPushButton {
  private:
    QPixmap _qPixmap;

  public:
    RoundButton(const QPixmap &qPixmap, QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QPushButton(pQParent),
      _qPixmap(qPixmap)
    {
      setMask(_qPixmap.mask());
    }
    virtual ~RoundButton() = default;
    RoundButton(const RoundButton&) = delete;
    RoundButton& operator=(const RoundButton&) = delete;

    virtual QSize sizeHint() const override;

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

QSize RoundButton::sizeHint() const { return _qPixmap.size(); }

void RoundButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  const int xy = isDown() * -2;
  qPainter.drawPixmap(xy, xy, _qPixmap);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPixmap qPixmap("./dialog-error.png");
  // setup GUI
  MainWindow qWin;
  qWin.setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("QPushButton with Mask"));
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  RoundButton qBtn(qPixmap);
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qBtn, &RoundButton::clicked,
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "RoundButton::clicked()"; });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The corresponding Qt project file `testQPushButtonMask.pro`

```
SOURCES = testQPushButtonMask.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQPushButtonMask.pro

$ make && ./testQPushButtonMask
Qt Version: 5.9.4
MainWindow::mousePressEvent: QPoint(23,22)
MainWindow::mousePressEvent: QPoint(62,24)
MainWindow::mousePressEvent: QPoint(62,61)
MainWindow::mousePressEvent: QPoint(22,60)
RoundButton::clicked()
```

[image: snapshot of testQPushButtonMask]

Concerning the output:

1. I clicked into the four corners of button.
2. I clicked on the center of button.

Comment: After referring the  Shaped Clock Example and changing the code in resizeEvent method it worked.
Thanks.

Comment: i have one more question. I am drawing an arc inside the paintEvent method, but i want to set RadialGradient to the arc. How can I set or pass QRadialGradient while drawing an arc?

Comment: @user3863360 Please, ask this as a new question. This increases the chances for a proper answer. I myself have never done this _but_ I would _guess_ that you may apply the gradient via a `QBrush`. Qt doc.: [Basic Drawing Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html).

Comment: @user3863360 I was wrong. I _have_ done it once for a rectangle and my guess was right. Construct the `QRadialGradient` object. Wrap it into a `QBrush`. The rest is from `QPainter` doc.: Set brush to use it with the `QPainter::drawPie()` or `QPainter::drawChord()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am drawing to draw arc, I don't get what I wanted using QPainter::drawPie() or QPainter::drawChord. I will ask in new question.